# windows service installation "Administrator access is needed"

Tags: windows, service, installation, administrator

I am using NSSM (the Non-Sucking Service Manager)  to install a windows service from a batch file like this

```
"nssm install C:\stash\runstash.bat"
```

but it throws:

```
"Administrator access is needed to install a service"
```

When I check user accounts in control panel, it shows that I am logged in with a User Name in the "Administrators" group.

Does anyone knows any possible reasons for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: flagged for migration to superuser. stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You running it from command line, right? Then run with admin rights. There few possible ways:

1. right click on cmd shortcut, the run as administrator
2. execute  cmd /admin

I believe you have UAC on on your PC, that's most programs run with user grant by defaul